# Altering variable in a method

Tags: java

```
private int myInt;

public var(int a)
myInt = a;

var x = new var(1)
var y = new var(5)
var z = y;
x = increment(y)     // where the increment method increments y by 1.
```

If the increment method alters the value of y, is the value of z also changed? In my book, when y is altered, z is also altered, but, how is that possible if z was already assigned to y before the increment method was called? Also I don't understand why x has anything assigned to it after the method. I thought that the scope of the method stays within the method; therefore after increment(y) exits, the value of x remains unchanged.

Please correct me if I am wrong because I am fairly new to programming.

Thank You!

Comment: Is var a constructor? If so, it's not a good one. You should give it a return type such as void to make it into a method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If it is a constructor, it will never finish completely because it will continue to construct itself.

Comment: @fireshadow52: indeed, I didn't see the recursion. Not good.

Comment: This question isn't really answerable until you show what `var` is.

Comment: @Rick Smith - You omitted curly brackets, so it's difficult to read your code, since we can't see where methods end.  Can you provide the **complete example**?

Comment: Sorry. Was trying to shorten the code. The return type is void.

Comment: @Rick Smith - If you are interested in the answer to your question you need to post a code sample that would at least compile.

Comment: Agree. If posting code, please post *real* code. Yours is crazy code that makes no sense. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

> If the increment method alters the value of y, is the value of z also changed?

It depends on the way `y` is altered: if the method assigns `y` a new value, `z` remains unchanged, because parameters in Java are passed by value, including object references. On the other hand, if the method alters the `int` *inside* the `var` object, then the `int` inside `z` is going to change as well, because that's the same object as `y`.

`x`, on the other hand, will be changed to whatever the `increment` method returns.

Comment: Your original answer was correct as well. **All** parameters in Java are passed by value. In case of objects their references are passed by value too.

Comment: Does x remain unchanged?

Comment: z, y and z are not of primitive types. They are objects.

Comment: @RickSmith I modified the answer to provide more details. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

`z` will remain unchanged. This is because programs run sequentially. After `y` has been assigned to `z` any changes in `y` won't affect `z`.

As for `x` it will equal whatever is returned by increment(y).

Comment: "This is because programs run sequentially." - What does that mean?

Comment: @PaulBellora 1 line of code is executed at a time in order.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I don't know why my book says that z also changes.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside the method, has method scope. You need to understand the concept of class and object. When you do var x = new var(1), you create a object from the var class and x is just a reference to that object. Same to y and when you assign y to z, you actually are making z refers to the same object y is referring.